# Adding a form to a web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to learn how to use methods from a web service into a C# form. I am following some examples, but i am confused on how exactly you add the reference from the form onto the web service and how can you use the methods from the Service.cs into the form's source code. I have left a picture to clarify what I need help understanding when it comes to how to properly link it:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200024/soap-web-service-vs2010-add-service-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click References->Add Service Reference Then a dialog will appear as follows,

[image]

Then create the client as follows,

```
  sampleSvc.CommonDataClient _client = new sampleSvc.CommonDataClient();
```

You can access the method like this,

```
 _client.CreateTable();
```

Comment: Very interesting, this works and now I am able to use those methods. But I still I am a little unsure about the "DesktopConsumer" form being repeated in the web service and on its own project. Any reason/benefit for this?

Comment: @user3386436 You must have been using the reference of it somewhere